problemas para cargar una vista
tengo un proyecto en laravel-livewire que me esta complicando la parte de mostrar en detalle tu la informacion de un usuario introducir la parte de livewire segun el mismo debug en esta parte tengo el error se manifiesta como http 500 o la pagina no funciona y no tengo ni idea de donde me equivoque
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class ShowUser extends Component
{
    public $user;

    public function mount($user)
    {
        // Aquí, $user es la ID del usuario que se pasa desde la ruta
        $this->user = User::findOrFail($user);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-user', ['user' => $this->user]);
    }
}

esta es la ruta
Route::get('/users/{user}', ShowUser::class)->name('users.show');
este es el boton donde voy a la vista que no me funciona
                    <a href="{{ route('users.show', ['user' => $user->id]) }}">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
                    </a>

